# Does large EF database models enormously spends app performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our project depends on one large MSSQL database. That database is exposed to many other apps. Some of which using an EF database first model. In that database there are over 300 tables. Some of them we need to use some of them are for other parts of app. When we reverse engineer the database, EF creates a model with all tables without any problems. Sometimes our code uses just one table but we still need to declare large model.

My question is, will performance suffer on an app if we always initialize a model with large amounts of tables in it.

What happening behind the scene when we have code like this

```
public string peaceOfData(int id)
{
    using (modelWhit500tables largeMode = new modelWhit500tables())
    {
        return largeMode.onlyOneTable.Find(id).data;
    }
}
```

Our apps are mostly MVC apps containing a number of Web-API Controllers.

We like to have one large model because of simplicity of database layer and easy maintenance for database design changes.

Comment: Just as a note, can't speak about EF insights about this perspective, but with NHibernate having _lot_ of models/maps can "hurt" performance when building up the SessionFactory, though there are workarounds to cache the xml mappings and reload from disk if it's not changed. However building up a Session Factory usually happens once per application pool startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be able to comment on the internals of EF, though [this post](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) answers your question at least in part:

> **Giant contexts**
>
> Even if you precompile views, Entity Framework still has to do work when a context is first initialized, and that work is
>   proportional to the number of entities in your model. For just a
>   handful of tables it’s not a lot to worry about.
>
> However, a common way of working with EF is to automatically generate a context from a pre-existing database, and to simply import
>   all objects. At the time this feels prudent as it maximizes your
>   ability to work with the database. Since even fairly modest databases
>   can contain hundreds of objects, the performance implications quickly
>   get out of control, and startup times can range in the minutes. It’s
>   worth considering whether your context actually needs to know about
>   the entire schema, and if not, to remove those objects.

Important to note is that the first time an instance of an application access the DB context, the context will go through the process of initializing it. This is what is referred to in the above quote. This happens only once for a application or web service, even if the context is disposed of by your code. It is a one-time performance hit for your application. You may want to trigger this explicitly at the startup of your application, rather than punishing the first user to access your application for this.

The performance considerations for EF are described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx). The biggest hit you most likely get with loading the model and mapping metadata. In your case, for MVC and Web API applications, it depends how you have your application domains defined:

[image]

Comment: "even if the context is disposed of by your code" sory for spamming. Is this a case also whit MVC conntoles and .NET Web Api contoles. If I right undestand your answer. Prefomance will surfer only first time when I use model. Every other time there is not much to wory about that. Even if model is used at other classes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the generated model with all 300 tables you could create your own dbContext using code-first approach. You can then work with a reduced surface view of the database. You can even ignore the fields that your application does not need for each table as well this way for better performance. As a simplified example using only 2 tables out of 300.

public class Customer 
    {
        public int id { get; set;}

```
    public string Custno { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    // The table other fields are ignored...

    public List<CustomerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }


    }
}

 public class CustomerAddress 
{
    public int id { get; set;}

    public int Customerid { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Cityname { get; set; }
    public string Statename { get; set; }
    public string Countryname { get; set; }
    public string Zipname { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }


}
    public class CustomerMap()
    {

        ToTable("Customers");

        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasKey(k => k.Id);

        Property(p => p.Custno).HasMaxLength(8).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(120).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.Balance).HasPrecision(18, 2);

        HasMany(a => a.Addresses).WithRequired(x => x.Customer).HasForeignKey(k => k.Customerid);  

    }

     public class CustomerAddressMap()
    {

        ToTable("CustomerAddresses");

        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasKey(k => k.Id);


        Property(p => p.Address1).HasMaxLength(120);
        Property(p => p.Address2).HasMaxLength(120);
        Property(p => p.Cityname).HasMaxLength(40);
        Property(p => p.Countryname).HasMaxLength(40);
        Property(p => p.Statename).HasMaxLength(40);
        Property(p => p.Zipname).HasMaxLength(6);


        HasRequired(x => x.Customer).WithMany(a => a.Addresses).HasForeignKey(k => k.Customerid).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }

    public class YourAppContext : DbContext
{
    public YourAppContext()
        : base("YourAppContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourAppContext>(null);     
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());            
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerAddressMap());      

    }


    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }


}
```

This way you can use YourAppContext to query and update only the table and fields you need.

Comment: Switching from DB first to code first may not be all that easy without some serious scaffolding. Also, your not answering the OP's question, but instead suggest a different approach to modelling the DB.